# How to set affinity

Tags: process

I want to execute 2 different programs on 2 different cores. I used taskset command to set affinity and assigned different cores to both programs. But I want to know whether these cores will be permanently assigned or not.I mean, will the program be executed on the same core all time or not???

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `taskset` to pin the program down to a core, it will stick to the core specified as long as it runs.